# How to change "dbpath" & "logpath" on windows 10 - mongodb 6.0.3

Tags: mongodb

I wanted to ask you how it's possible to change the `"dbpath"` & `"logpath"` on windows 10 and with mongodb version 6.0.3? I tried a few solutions but they don't really work.

I created manually the `dbpath` folder because the `logpath` folder already exists. The folders are located: `"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0"`.

For the `"dbpath"` first i wrote the following line: `mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0"` the output that i get is: https://ibb.co/6vNg4Fn

Then, typing `mongosh` for shell, it connects but when i create a new database, it's not shown in the new path.

I should note that i use `mongod` as a service and always on. I even tried to change the directory at `mongod.cfg` file, but it's not changing either.

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: When you run just `mongod.exe` then it does not use any configuration file (i.e. directory at mongod.cfg file has no effect at all) Looks like `mongod` is already running, you can run it only once unless you configure different port and different  `dbPath` (and preferably also different logPath)

Comment: The MongoDB server log shows (please, please just copy/paste the text into a code block - don't use images) that the `dbpath` is _`"read-only"`_.  That needs to be fixed so the server can write there.